# Нужен ли предлог "в": (в) сердце с болью

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Каждый день сердце с болью,
Вспоминаем о тебе с любовью...

Подскажите, нужен ли предлог *в* перед словом *сердце*?

Comment: Лена! Как я понимаю, эти строки посвящены навсегда ушедшему дорогому человеку. Я сам недавно был в такой ситуации (пытаясь придумать текст для памятника), так что соболезную и сочувствую. В то же время хочу сказать, что нужно подойти к делу осторожно, так как в такой ситуции стилистические ошибки могут восприниматься особенно болезненно. Какую мысль Вы хотите выразить?  Вспомимаем тебя каждый день с болью в сердце и с любовью? Или "Каждый день проходит с болью в сердце. Вспоминаем о тебе с любовью"? Вспоминаем тебя или о тебе?

Answer (score 1):

В качестве варианта:

**Каждый день в сердце с болью Вспоминаем о тебе (тебя) с любовью...**

Здесь использована инверсия: **с болью в сердце**. Предложение простое, запятая не нужна.

Comment: Я склонен поддержать этот вариант. Только мне ближе "вспоминаем тебя". По-моему, вспоминаем тебя — это сознательно вызванные воспоминания о человеке, в связи с чем уместнее говорить "с любовью, с болью"; вспоминаем о тебе — непроизвольные вспышки памяти.

Comment: Да, прямое дополнение здесь больше подойдет.